# Multiple pages with the same layout but different content

Tags: php, mysql, html

So basically what I want is a site like this:

```
Name:

Date:

(picture of person)
```

But I don't want to have to create a new page by hand for every person (thousands of people). I have all the content needed in a database. Is there a way for me to have it where they click on the persons name in a table on the previous page and have it generate a page with that persons content on it?

Comment: Fairly simple coding, depending on the language you choose to use and which DB you are connecting to.  If you show us what you've got, you might get help finishing it - but I doubt many of us would just write it for you.

Comment: You have to gather all the data you want to display on user's page and pass it on to your HTML file.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display User</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      // Write all the queries here, by using $_GET to fetch the content
      // from the url. You might also want to include the user id in the url.
      // Finally, fetch the rows as $row = ...
    ?>
    Name: <?php echo $row['name']; ?><br /><br />
    Date: <?php // Do what you want with the date here ?><br /><br />
    <img src="<?php echo $row['imglocation']; // Change this parameter to fit your needs" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic principle is to request each record with ie an ID from the db. So URL could be person.php?id=xxx where xxx is the ID corresponding to the db record.

Then in the person.php you would use $_GET['id'] for getting the right record from the DB. Of course you will need to escape inputs to secure the DB...

Comment: Hmmm, no this is very messy. First $_GET is only the URI variable sent fron your person list (another document. Secondly  you need to just get one row from the db table, and I suggest you use the ID. So code should be "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = $_GET['id'] (escaped!!!) " Then you need to fetch the data to an array with mysql_fetch_assoc or similar and then all the data would be inserted into the page from that array (not $_GET array)...